# For GIS questions using hybrid JavaScript frameworks, where should questions be posted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, stack-exchange

I have been a user for Stack Exchange for quite sometime now. Recently I started using StackGIS, and it's quite helpful in terms of the difficulties I ask, which mostly range in JavaScript and [OpenLayers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLayers).

I believe that a question pertaining to JavaScript and OpenLayers would take a moderate level of expertise and asking such a question on stackGIS would be apt. Now recently I migrated to AngularJS, so now I am using a combination of OpenLayers and AngularJS.

It is important to realise here that AngularJS is a hybrid JavaScript framework and would take more than just a moderate level of expertise. Now would it still be correct for me to post on stackGIS? I mean, even though my question pertains to OpenLayers (which is a mapping library).

Basically to put it in a nutshell, which using a hybrid framework like AngularJS, is it more apt to post the query on Stack Overflow or stackGIS?

Comment: Ask yourself this: the people posting on GIS, *can* they answer questions about generic AngularJS questions? *should* they be the ones to answer them? I don't think so. IMO don't pick a site to ask questions, pick a target audience you want answers from.

Comment: Well, there's only 14 questions [tagged angularjs on GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). Is it more important to have a good understanding of openlayers or angular?

Comment: @Gimby Thanks , that does make sense !

Comment: @BSMP i would say angular , but in the same breath , when i post questions about openlayers on SO , i have seen people struggle to answer them, when similar questions are easily answered on stackGIS

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik in that observation you find a great personal responsibility: when asking about angularjs, better make the effort to keep any other technology out of the picture. Let me put it in a silly way: if you ask questions about building software for space ships with javascript, better keep the questions about javascript programming such that you don't need to know how space ships work.

Comment: @Gimby exactly !!! :) but in the same breath , i highly doubt , such a philosophy can be applied everytime to every question.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik and so you find out there are a subset of questions where in fact you are the domain expert that needs to research and develop both the question and the answer to share it, not to consume it. Stackexchange needs YOU! (imagine a picture of a old guy pointing a finger at you with a stern look)

Comment: I'm not able to suggest an edit here but the [gis.se] Stack Exchange (of which I am a moderator) is almost always abbreviated as GIS SE rather than StackGIS or stackGIS as used in this post.

Answer (score 2):

Which is the appropriate site to ask a particular programming question about OpenLayers and AngularJS will depend on where it falls on the pure OpenLayers to pure AngularJS spectrum.

If it is near pure AngularJS then Stack Overflow is the obvious choice and as it tends towards pure OpenLayers, then the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) comes into its own.

If in doubt, then if you post it to the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) (where I am a moderator), we are well aware of Stack Overflow and are used to diverting questions or parts of questions to Stack Overflow if they are not about GIS.

The OpenLayers Q&As of GIS SE include:

- [OpenLayers 3 & 4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers)
- [OpenLayers 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2)
- [QGIS OpenLayers plug-in](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-openlayers-plugin)